# FasterXML Issues while marsahaling to XML

Tags: java, xml, jackson, fasterxml, woodstox

I am trying to marsahall Objects to XML using jackson-dataformat-xml and woodstax but its adding additional namespace prefix wstxns1. Any suggestions ?

My Beans look like as below

```
    @JacksonRootElement(localname="Blah" namespace="http://something"
    Bla {

    @JacksonXMLProperty(localname="SomeProperty" namespace="http://something"
    String SomePropety;

 @JacksonXMLProperty(localname="SomeClass" namespace="http://something-different"
    Class SomeClass;
    ....
```

Comment: What have you tried? I know there are lots of tutorials for this, you should start there before asking for help.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Which version of Jackson and Woodstox are you using?

Comment: Jackson - 2.3 and WoodStox 4.1.4

Comment: @JamesKingsbery - The problem is jackson-dataformat-xml and woodstox doesn't have much of Tutorial and whatever there are , they are plain and simple. They are not that active too on Stackoverflow where i get a response after 16 hours .. compare it with any other Qs asked here .. Also a google search would lead to a limited search Result ...

Comment: @user1428716 Still unable to reproduce. Can you post the code that does conversion to XML?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want one of following:

1. Define "default namespace" (one with no prefix) to bind to URI for element, to avoid prefix -- this is only possible for a single namespace at a time. OR,
2. Make Woodstox use some other base for prefixes it generates as needed
3. You would like to offer suggestion for prefix to use (since Stax `XMLStreamWriter` allows this).

Jackson XML module does not have mechanisms for handling prefixes at this point (although RFEs and pull requests are welcome).
But Woodstox itself has fair bit of configurability, beyond basic Stax API (which is quite limited).

The places to look beyond (documentation, blogs) for additional configuration properties for output are classes:

1. `org.codehaus.stax2.XMLOutputFactory2` for Stax2 extension properties (implemented by Woodstox and Aalto)
2. `com.ctc.wstx.api.WstxOutputProperties` for Woodstox-specific properties

and these properties are set via `XMLOutputFactory.setProperty()`, same as standard Stax properties.

Property of interest here would be `org.codehaus.stax2.XMLOutputFactory2#P_AUTOMATIC_NS_PREFIX`, which defaults to "wstxns" but can be changed to any other valid XML id String.

Beyond this, it may be possible to specify pre-configured `XMLStreamWriter` for Jackson XML module to use. If so, it would also be possible to use standard Stax method ("writeNamespace()" I think?) to create specific prefix-to-URL namespace bindings.

Finally, Jackson mailing lists are the best place to ask questions. Developers like myself do read StackOverflow and other forums as well, but latency tends to be higher as you have noticed.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope we can resolve issues you have and solve your use case -- libs like Jackson improve best with help of active users.

Comment: it's been a while since @StaxMan suggested the solution. As I have bumped into the same issue, I'd like to make this more explicit, since as of Jackson 2.11 WstxInputProperties does not map Stax2 property P_AUTOMATIC_NS_PREFIX. This simple line will remove (or change if that is what is wanted) the default prefix: `xmlMapper.getFactory().getXMLOutputFactory().setProperty("org.codehaus.stax2.automaticNsPrefix", "");`